# Datatable cannot initialise

Tags: jquery, datatables

I tried to recal a datatable with this code

```
$('#tableid').DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
```

It wont work, and it produces this errormessage: DataTables warning: table id=tableidt - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

I read here https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3 but I do not know how I should do this with my code above.

I think this can solve the problem

```
table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    retrieve: true,
} );
```

I don't know how I can make this with my code

```
$('#tableid').DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
```

I've tried with this, but it failed

```
 $('#tableid').DataTable({
                  destroy: true,
                  //retrieve: true, also tested but failed, too
                  }).columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
```

How I can solve the error?

Comment: what's purpose behind initializing it again? may be there is another way to achieve the goal, so if you could explain why you're trying this, can help understand the scenario better.

Comment: @Pirate sure. I need to recalc the table after changing the width of the table.

Comment: in my experience `retrieve: true` should fix the issue. It has worked for me. but if it's not working for you than I am afraid there is anything else. May be try [destroying datatable](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) and reinitialize again. Or when you first initialize it, store the datatable instance in a local variable and then use that to access APIs.

Comment: @Pirate i've trie it with retrieve, is the way i do it correct?

Comment: I am not sure how you initialize it. perhaps post a full script where you initialize the table and recalculate the width. have you put `retrieve: true` in original initialization code?

Comment: @Pirate on initialization i ve not the retrieve part only on the reclac part like in my post above

Comment: Try adding `retrieve: true` on original initialization. You can then do `$('#tableid').DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing a lot of ways, i finaly use this to prevent the error message.

I think that this is not the best way and i think it wont solve the mainproblem but it works for me.

```
if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable(#tableid) ) {
                  alert("DT way1");
                  $(#tableid).DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();  
            }
            else {
                  alert("DT way2");
//do nothing
            }
```